# How to correctly use any and/or unknown for function arguments

Tags: javascript, typescript

We're trying to convert an event bus from JavaScript to TypeScript. What concerns us is this piece of code:

```js
export function publish(eventName, ...args) {
  if (!subscriptions[eventName]) { return }

  for (const callback of subscriptions[eventName]) {
     const result = callback(...args)

     if (result === false) { break }
  }
}
```

Translated to TypeScript:

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
type TCallBack = (...args: any) => void

const subscriptions: { [key: string]: TCallBack[] } = {}

export function publish(eventName: string, ...args: unknown[]) {
  if (!subscriptions[eventName]) { return }

  for (const callback of subscriptions[eventName]) {
    callback(...args)
  }
}
```

There are no errors but I'm not quite sure that we used the `any` and `unknown` type correctly for the arguments of `callback`. A `callback` can have one, multiple or no arguments at all and the argument can be of any type. Is this the correct way of using `any` and `unknown>`

Comment: you should add the "optional" operator to ...args: ...args?: unknown[]

Comment: I'd expect a spread type like `...args` to be minimally an array type, so maybe `any[]`. Also shouldn't the callback return a Boolean? You're comparing its return value to false in the first example, it's unclear to me why translating to typescript required a change to the actual *behaviour*.

Comment: Because if I kept `if (result === false)` in I got this TS error "This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'void' and 'boolean' have no overlap."

Comment: I guess @jonrsharpe meant that you should add `boolean` as a valid return type of `TCallBack`: `type TCallBack = (...args?: unknown[]) => boolean | void`

Comment: @SandroSchaurer it doesn't make sense for a rest arg to be optional (and I think TS will complain) - if there aren't any, it becomes an empty array, not undefined.